# How do I switch desktop environment on Debian 11 if there is no gear button while logging in?

Tags: debian, desktop-environment

I've installed debian and I included desktop environments while installation. I also checked them with tasksel and it shows them installed:

```
mykola@debian:~
> apt show task-desktop              
Package: task-desktop
Version: 3.68
Priority: optional
Section: tasks
Source: tasksel
Maintainer: Debian Install System Team <debian-boot@lists.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 6,144 B
Depends: tasksel (= 3.68), xorg, xserver-xorg-video-all, xserver-xorg-input-all, desktop-base
Recommends: task-gnome-desktop | task-xfce-desktop | task-kde-desktop | task-lxde-desktop | task-gnome-flashback-desktop | task-cinnamon-desktop | task-mate-desktop | task-lxqt-desktop, xdg-utils, fonts-symbola, avahi-daemon, libnss-mdns, anacron, eject, iw, alsa-utils, sudo, firefox | firefox-esr
Download-Size: 1,036 B
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
Description: Debian desktop environment
 This task package is used to install the Debian desktop.
```

I have searched a lot how to switch desktop environment and many say "just press the gear button when logging in." And I don't have it!

[image]

like here: [image]

Any suggestions?
Changing that a "headless way" was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3):

Users can end up with password prompts in a number of situations, and only one of them shows the gear icon leading to a selection of desktop environments.

To be able to choose a desktop environment, you need to start from the user selection list, something like

[image: GNOME user list]

Select the user to get the password prompt; then you’ll see the gear icon:

[image: GNOME password entry with gear icon and list of desktop environments]

The screenshot in your question shows the lock screen, which is displayed when the user is logged in. In this situation, the password entry screen has a similar layout to the screen shown when logging in, but it usually has a different background, it can show certain notifications, and it shows a “people” icon instead of the gear icon:

[image: GNOME lock screen with password entry]

The “people” icon takes the user back to the user list; this allows multiple sessions to be opened in parallel by different users.

This leads to a third variant of the password entry screen. When a user is already logged in, the login password entry screen doesn’t allow changing desktop environments (since the user already has a running session), and the gear icon isn’t displayed:

[image: GNOME password entry screen without the gear icon]

To get back to the login screen *with* gear icon from your lock screen, you need to enter your password to log back in, then log out; that will take you back to the user selection screen, and selecting a user will show you the password entry screen with the gear icon allowing you to choose your desktop environment.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't have a user list, but when I typed in the username and hit ENTER, the icon appeared. In my opinion that's a UX bug.

Comment: Each user can have a different DE selected as their default; I think that’s why the DE selection list is only available once a specific user is chosen (either from a list or by entering a login).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using lightdm then it's up above right (see pic below)
[image: lightdm]